# Using custom dash pattern for polygon outline (simple fill) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am trying to use a custom dash pattern for a polygon outline with a simple fill but I can't use anything other than the presets (see the screenshot)

[image]

I am using QGIS but looking for something similar to the "Cartographic Line Symbol" from ArcMap.

I know it is possible with a Simple Line, but is that achievable with the outline of a Simple Fill?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a second layer style to your simple fill and set it to be a simple line. From there you can customize the dash-pattern. Don't forget, on the simple fill layer, to turn off the outline.

[image]